# Java deadlock situation with threaddump containing object owned by "null"

Tags: java, multithreading, aem

I have accessed thread-dump of a staging web-server which has multiple threads waiting on different objects. One **Timer thread** has access to *0x13e30613* object and waiting on *0x2fa1056c*.

```
"Timer-17637" prio=5 tid=0x75e4 nid=0xffffffff in Object.wait()
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.base@11.0.8/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - waiting to lock <0x2fa1056c> (a java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch$Sync) owned by "null" tid=0x-1
    at java.base@11.0.8/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)
    ..... 
    .....
    - locked <0x13e30613> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.base@11.0.8/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:556)
    at java.base@11.0.8/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:506)
```

But the thread-does not mention which thread has locked *0x2fa1056c* object. No other thread-stack mentions anything about *0x2fa1056c* object. Most of the other threads are waiting on *0x13e30613* object held by the Timer thread which is causing a deadlock like situation. How do I figure out which thread owns the *0x2fa1056c* object ?

---

EDITED: Gist containing the logs https://gist.github.com/riteshksriv/3b249eb56e0500a9234cd2470152d730

Comment: What is your problem exactly

Comment: @akortex91 well, the question mentions it already: there's a lock on one object that the central timer thread is waiting for. However that `owned by "null" tid=0x-1` indicates there is no thread owning the lock so the question is how to find out who is holding that lock so that this situation can be fixed/prevented.

Comment: Does your stacktrace show any `blocked` threads?

Comment: @akortex91 Yes. All the threads waiting for 0x13e30613 are in BLOCKED state

Comment: Also the Timer thread is in WAITING state

Comment: Please share the rest of your stack dump.

Comment: Gist containing the stack https://gist.github.com/riteshksriv/3b249eb56e0500a9234cd2470152d730

Comment: @akortex91 Any help would be really appreciated